# how to but container at the bottom of page

Tags: flutter

I am trying to put the white container at the bottom of the page how I can do that, I don't want to give a padding top because this will affect other screens' sizes. Is there a way to put the whole white container at the bottom of the page it at the bottom of the screen?

here is an image :[image]

here is my code :
`

```
class SignIn extends StatelessWidget {
  const SignIn({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          "Text",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Stack(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: height * 0.05,
                      left: 10,
                      right: 20,
                    ),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(30),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                              child: Text(
                                "Sign In",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 25,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 25,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Text("End"),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 50),
                        child: Container(
                          height: 60,
                          width: 60,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                            color: Colors.green,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

you wanted this

[image]

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                    child: Stack(
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "Text",
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Stack(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: height * 0.05,
                          left: 10,
                          right: 20,
                        ),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                            topRight: Radius.circular(30),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Sign In",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 25,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 25,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 20,
                            ),
                            Container(
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  Text("End"),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 50),
                            child: Container(
                              height: 60,
                              width: 60,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                color: Colors.green,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I want only the white container to be at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Column(
                      children: [
                       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                              child: Text(
                                "Sign In",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 25,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
```